# How to reveal <app-header condenses reveals fixed> immediately when slide back up without scrolling to top

Tags: polymer, polymer-elements

Referring to the following code:-

```
 <app-header-layout has-scrolling-region>

    <app-header condenses reveals fixed effects="waterfall">
      <app-toolbar style="height: 48px;">
        <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
        <div title>My App</div>
      </app-toolbar>
      <app-toolbar primary style="height: 48px;">
        <paper-tabs attr-for-selected="name" fallback-selection="tab-1" selected={{selected}} style="width: 100%" noink scrollable>
          <paper-tab name="tab-1">Tab 1</paper-tab>
          <paper-tab name="tab-2">Tab 2</paper-tab>
        </paper-tabs>
      </app-toolbar>
    </app-header>

    <iron-pages role="main" selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name">
      <my-view1 name="view1"></my-view1>
      <my-view2 name="view2"></my-view2>
      <my-view3 name="view3"></my-view3>
    </iron-pages>

  </app-header-layout>
```

I intend to fixed the paper-tabs, and reveal the first app-toolbar immediately when slide back up. Currently I have to scroll to top for the first app-toolbar to reveal itself.

Does anybody knoow what's the proper way to achieve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just want the share that the problem has been fixed in `0.9.1`

https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout/issues/232